# Using jQuery UI to slide content rather than fade?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

First off, I want to apologize for not having a public demo and also being very new to jQuery.

There currently is in place a very basic jQuery "slider" script that fires a fadeIn for new content that just layered in on top (from what I can tell). I am attempting to change this effect to a Slide effect using easing, and by including jQueryUI (currently not included).

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var current_featured = 1;
var current_featured_index = 100;
var featured_interval_time = 4000;
var featured_interval = setInterval("advance_featured()", featured_interval_time);

function advance_featured() {
    featured = current_featured + 1;
    if (featured > 4) {
        featured = 1;    
    }
    switch_featured(featured);
}

function switch_featured(featured) {
    current_featured = featured;
    current_featured_index += 10;
    $(".home-featured-post-link").css( { "z-index" : current_featured_index + 10 } );
    $("#home-featured-post-" + current_featured).css( { "z-index" : current_featured_index, "display" : "none" } ).fadeIn();
}

$("#home-featured").hover(
    function() { clearInterval(featured_interval); },
    function() { featured_interval = setInterval("advance_featured()", featured_interval_time); });
</script>
```

Right now it is currently rotating through four basic blocks. I am not attempting to do anything but change the animation from a fadeIn effect to a sliding animation. I would like to slide out the old block while sliding in the new block, but this is not needed. I am trying to keep the change simple.

Thanks,

Comment: create public demo and include some pictures illustrating your idea

Comment: Hey,

Here is the url where it is located: http://survey.cvent.com/